# AutoGenerate Identity Negative PK in EF4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.4.0.0 and following custom methods for generating identity negative PK:

```
    private int? GetMinId()
    {
        return Context.ENTITY.Min(c => (int?)c.Id);
    }

    public int GenerateNegativeId()
    {
        var minId = GetMinId() ?? default(int);

        if (0 < minId) return minId * -1;
        if (0 > minId) return --minId;

        return -1;
    }
```

Could you explain how to **AutoGenerate Identity Negative PK** ids. (Is it possible?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because identity generation happens on the database side. Why do you need this, why can't you just order your rows?

Comment: Thanks, I need this because I'm writing client app which will be sync with server.

Comment: Perhaps a better option would be to use GUIDs (those can be generated by the database), and use them as a sync key. That's how we do it.

Comment: I can't change models, so I need to use int for PK