# assign negative value for the created entities in the Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to let the entity framework to assign a negative for the added entities for example

```
 1. Customer { Id = -1} when i add it to entity framework
 2. Customer { Id = -2}
 3. Address { Id = -1}
```

note: this option is available in DataSet

I hope that I explained my question in clear way

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoGenerate Identity Negative PK in EF4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929859/autogenerate-identity-negative-pk-in-ef4)

Comment: What you mean by "Added entities"?

Comment: Added means the entry State= EntityState.Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
public class Customer
{
    private static int FakeId=0;
    public Customer()
    {
        Id = --FakeId;
    }
}
```